# why to use select statement even though inserting values in sql server database,using entity framework MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am very new to the MVC,Entity framework application and am still learning. I have a query.
I am inserting the values in SQL server database using Entity Framework and MVC application with the stored procedure. I am using the DB first approach. I want to ask why I need to add an select statement even though I have written the procedure to insert the values. If I dont write the select statement then it throws the error.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EmployeeDBModel.Employee'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertEmployees]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @Address varchar(50),
    @Salary int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Insert into Employee values(@FirstName,@LastName,@Address,@Salary)

    --select scope_identity() as Id,Firstname,LastName,Address,Salary from Employee
END
```

If I uncomment `select` command it just work.

Note:- `Id` is identity column and auto seed is true

**Model :-**

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Salary { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee emp)
{
    using (EmployeeDBEntities db = new EmployeeDBEntities())
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.InsertEmpDetail(emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, emp.Address, emp.Salary);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.Message = "New Employee Created Successfully!!";
        }
    }
    return View(emp);
}
```

I have created the function `InsertEmpDetail` and mapped it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think if I dont remember it wrongly , when you map you entity, the orm entity framework will need to be able to read for the entity through certaion way. (sorry cant get to my net computer, but in java it often the same).

I'm guessing that your procedure have return result thus the will be read onto the entity.

another possibililty is the commit of the stored procedure, since it cant be read after insert properly, the column seems to be missing.

(just saying this have happen to me before)

good luck,
edd